# get true file url after user uploads in django

Tags: python, django

here is the problem. in my project user is going to upload an excel file and right after that the app must take it and read it using `pandas`. file is uploaded in `media/projects/%Y/%m/%d/`:

`views.py`:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['createdatabase']:
    user = request.user
    data = request.FILES['createdatabase']

    new = NewProject(
            user=user,
            data=data,
        )
    new.save()
```

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class NewProject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    data = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='projects/%Y/%m/%d/')
    u = models.TextField(blank=True)
    v = models.TextField(blank=True)
    w = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

`u`, `v`, and `w` are in the data file that the user uploads and the app must read it. when I want to read the file in `pandas` using the `read_excel()` method, it needs the file URL. using `data.url` or `data.path` does not work seems it just says the file name or the wrong path `media/datafilename.xlsx`. the true file URL must be something like `media/2022/07/01/datafilename.xlsx`. also, some files might have the same names that are uploaded by the users. so the Django just adds a random string to it. but `data.url` and `data.path` print the main name of the file. not the changed one. 
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

```py
from datetime import datetime
from uuid import uuid4

def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/projects/<year>/<month>/<day>/<filename>
    ext = filename.split(".")[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid4(), ext)
    today = datetime.now()
    today_path = today.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
    return 'projects/{0}/{1}'.format(today_path, filename)

class NewProject(models.Model):
    data = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

For accessing the uploaded file,

```
project.data.path  # etc: '/media/projects/2022/07/02/4cc38320-556c-490a-90d5-f8834bf75275.xlsx'
```

Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Comment: Thank you very much. this did exactly what I wanted.